# 403 Forbidden - while updating list items through sharepoint hosted apps

Tags: sharepoint-hosted-app

[image]

an above snap item updating calls GET Items which need to be updated but got 403 Forbidden error in sharepoint hosted apps.

My Apps and list in the same domain.

i took reference from this side for update items. it works fine in console but not working in inside app.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/uksharepoint/archive/2013/02/22/manipulating-list-items-in-sharepoint-hosted-apps-using-the-rest-api.aspx

App having fullcontrol permission on site collection and web level

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Could you paste your  code in the question. Also is the list in host web or app web?

Comment: Are you using the app only permissions if so does it have contribute access and was trusted on the target site.

Comment: updated question